# Excel to compare parameter values of XML table

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I am Excel newbie and I have two (Book1, Sheet1 and Book2, Sheet1) XML table in Excel as below example -

```
Book1, Sheet1 (Column - O (value, it can be numeric/alphanumeric/alphabets) & P (parameter name), total 12000 row):

EMERALD Name                                                      
2   ForPS  
10  InitWait   
11  1stInterv   
20  Interv   
10  UL_DLcapacity   
2   ChangeOrigin   
0   LCSfunct305          
70  TraceVertAccur  

Book2, SHeet1 (Column - O & P, total 12000 row):


11  1stInterv    
26  Interv    
0   LCSfunct305   
RUBY    Name     
2   ForPS    
10  InitWait         
10  UL_DLcapacity       
2   ChangeOrigin
```

Excel needs to do as below (I am not sure macro or formula will be better to do this) -

- For the parameter value in column O (Book1, Sheet1) find the
  corrosponding value of that parameter in book2, sheet1, column O and
  then if the values are different, change the color (for example -
  Pink) of the cell of that parameter name in Book1, Sheet1 Column P.
- If any of the parameter name in book1&sheet1&column P is not found in
  Book2&Sheet1&column P then change the color (for example - red) of
  that corrusponding parameter cell in book1&sheet1&column P.

Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if the data your provided is correct but as I can see few values in sheet 1 is repetitive with different parameter name for eg `10  InitWait` and `10  UL_DLcapacity`, so how would I know which value is correct. Or are you trying to say you want to compare cell by cell i.e if `cell (O1) in sheet 1 is equal to cell(O1)` in sheet2?

Comment: to be more, clear, excel will compare InitWait parameter value (10) in Book1 with the InitWait parameter value (10) in Book2. In this case, the values are same, so Excel will not chnage the color of the cell of InitWait parameter in book1.

but for the parameter Interv, value is different in Book2. so, in this case Excel needs to change the color of the cell of Interv parameter in book1.

Comment: Do you have the provision of `interchanging column O and P` i.e column `P will come to O and O will move to P` (in both the sheets), if yes I have a ready made solution, else I need to work out. If you can interchange write back, ill post the solution for you

Comment: yes inter changing is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what you need to do

- In both `book1 and book2` interchange the columns as discussed
  earlier (`Value will move to column P and Parameter Name will move to
  Column O`)
- In `book2 in columnQ` insert the following formula
  `=P1-VLOOKUP($O1,[book1.xlsx]Sheet1!O$1:P$8,2,0)` what this will basically do is find the corresponding value from `book1` for each `Parameter Name` and then substract itself from the value in `book2`. If the value is not found it will return an `error (#N/A)`
- Now to change the color of Parameter Name we need to use `Conditional Formatting` like this
- Select the `first Item` on `column o` in `book2`
- Click on `Conditional Formatting` on `home tab menu` and `Click on New rule`
- `Click on Use a formula to determine which cell to format`
- On the `Edit the Rule Description` use this formula `=ISERROR($Q1)` and format the font/background to your desired Color. This will highlight any values that are not found from the `book1`
- Again Click on `Conditional Formatting` on `home tab menu` and `Click on New rule`
- On the `Edit the Rule Description` use this formula `=$Q1<>0`
  and format the font/background to your desired Color. This will
  highlight any values that is not same as in `book1`
- Finally you need to copy the formatting from `first item` to rest of the item in `book2 column o`. For copy the first item and use `paste special` and paste only the `format` in rest of the items (or whole `column O` if you so desire). For paste special you can also copy the first item and use short cut key (ALT->E->S->T) to pate the format only

[image: Working Solution for your reference]

Comment: not sure if I correctly accepted the answer, if anything left just tell me I will do that. actually this is the 1st time I am using this site.